# Test rest api return 302

Tags: laravel, rest, laravel-resource

I use rest API.

For example, requwest http://api/events/?api_token=KFvcc10H4l return me json.

But in test I get error 302

```
   /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function testReturnOneEventsItem()
    {
         $this->get( '/events/3?api_token=KFvcc10H4l')
                //  $response = $this->get('http://api/events');
                ->assertStatus(200);
    }
```

Solution:

Need wreti data for test. Unit test not use you database.

```
$event = factory(Event::class)->create();
        $user = factory(User::class)->create();
        $this->get('events/' . $event->id . '?&api_token=' . $user->api_token)
                ->assertStatus(200)->assertJson([
                        'id' => $event->id,
                        'title' => $event->title,
                        'city_id' => strval($event->city_id),
                ]);;
```

Comment: Missing the `api/` part?

Comment: if I add http://api in not help. But   ```$this->get('http://api/',$server)->assertStatus(200);``` work

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `status code 302` because the resource you are requesting for has already been moved to a temporal location.
Your code will successfully return the requested API but still return a `status code 302` and I actually think this is because it has already been stored in the location requesting for it.

If a source request for an API for the first time and receives the requested resource successfully, `status code 200` is returned. Subsequent calls, therefore, will only return status code 302.

Follow the [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302) to read more about `status code 302`.

Comment: Now 401. I use ->middleware('auth:api')- for this route and not understand, why it work for external requests, but not work for Features test

Comment: After you added the `auth-api` middleware did it still work for just test or it stopped working for both test and external requests?

Comment: I understand. For test Laravel use temp database, And for the test, you first need to write the data in the test itself.